# BeautifulSoup : how to iterate over unclosed tag

Tags: python, html, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

how to itterate through unclosed tag in html or xml  with beautifulsoup?
I want to access every tag that is not closed.

Comment: html5lib library will do it

Comment: @SmartManoj is it possible with Beautifulsoup?

Comment: S [html5lib](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) will automatically pairs with a corresponding tag